# How to add Custom LogLevel to Apache Camel .log()

Tags: java, apache-camel, log4j2

I want to create a custom loglevel to use it in some routes:

```
.from(xyz)
  .log(LoggingLevel.CUSTOM,"My Text")
  ...
```

or

```
.from(xyz)
  .log(LoggingLevel.valueOf("CUSTOM"),"My Text")
  ...
```

I use Camel with Spring. I insert this to log4j2.xml:

```
<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="CUSTOM" intLevel="301" />
</CustomLevels>
```

But I get the Error Message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel.CUSTOM
```

What can I do?

Comment: Can you try to do the same as described here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html and use `Level` instead of `LoggingLevel`?

Comment: I doubt that this can work. Camel does not use log4j directly, it uses slf4j instead and lets you choose the actual logging framework. So you are limited to what the slf4j API offers to Camel, I guess.

Comment: @metters: this not work, because the declaration from .log is public Type log(LoggingLevel loggingLevel, String message)